# Number of zeros of a polynomial modulo n is a multiplicative function

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

Let $f$ be a polynomial with integer coeffcients. For $n\geq1$ let $N_f(n)$ denote the number of pairwise incongruent solutions of $f(x)=0$ mod n. I need help proving that $f$ is a multiplicative function. I tried building an isomorphism between the zeros of f mod m cross zeros of f mod n to zeros of f mod mn, and I send these to their multiplication, but I don't know how to prove that if x is a zero of $f$ mod n, and y a zero of $f$ mod m where nm are co-prime that xy is a zero of $f$ mod mn.

Comment: Let $ f(z)=z+1$  for all $z$ .Let $ m=1$ .Let $n=2$ .Let $x=2$ .Let $ y=1$ . Then  $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod m$ and $ f(y)\equiv 0\pmod n$ but $f(x y)\not \equiv 0 \pmod {mn}$.

Comment: your function is still multiplicative

Answer (score 1):

For positive integers $ m,n$   with $GCD(m.n)=1$ : If $1\le a\le m$  and $1\le b\le n $, there is a unique $S(a,b)$ such that $1\le S(a,b)\le m n$  and  $ S(a,b)\equiv a\pmod m$  and $S(a,b)\equiv b\pmod n $ .PROOF: (1)Existence.The set $ T= \{a+zm : z \in Z \text{ and }1\leq a+zm\le mn\}$ is a complete residue class  modulo $ n$  because $GCD(m,n)=1 $ .So  $t\equiv b \pmod n$ for some $t\in T $ . (2)Uniqueness.If $1\le t\le m n$ and $1\le t^8\le m n$ with  $t\equiv t^*\equiv a\pmod m$  and $t\equiv t^*\equiv b\pmod n$ then  $|t-t^*|$ is divisible by both $ m$  and $n$, which implies that  $m n$ divides $|t-t^*|$  (Again, because $GCD(m,n)=1 $ .But $0\le |t-t^*|<m n $, so $t-t^*=0.$ $$NOW$$ to show that your function is multiplicative, let $A=\{a :1\le a\le m \text { and } f(a)\equiv 0\pmod m\}$ and $B=\{b : 1\le b\le n \text{ and }f(b)\equiv 0\pmod n\}$. Then  $ \forall (a,b)\in A\times B (f(S(a,b)) \equiv 0 \pmod {m n}.$ (Is this obvious?) But if $1\le x \le m$  and $1\le y\le n$ and $(x,y)\not \in A\times B$ then  $f((x,y))\not \equiv 0\pmod m$ OR $f(S(x,y))\not \equiv 0 \pmod n$....... Since $S$ is a 1-to-1 function, we are done.